# how to write fluent nhibernate queries?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I'm new to fluent nhibernate and generally nhibernate.
I searched a lot on the net but I couldn't find a good help.
I'm using fluent nhibernate and I mapped it with SQLServer 2008.
If there is a good help or book or sth else please tell me!

First of all I want to know how I can write native sql queries in my program? for example
    `DELETE * From SiteCategory`
And generally I want to know how to write queries in fluent nhibernate? such as update,delete and select.

Answer (score 4):

A good resource would be this series of screencasts:

Vacation Of Fluent NHibernate:
http://iamnotmyself.com/2009/10/26/vacation-of-fluent-nhibernate-introduction/
[link updated]

It was modeled after the very popular Summer of NHibernate series

Comment: link in the answer does not work. this should work http://iamnotmyself.com/2009/10/26/vacation-of-fluent-nhibernate-introduction/

Comment: N30 - Thanks, it looks like the blog author has changed blog engines with a different url scheme.